# $\log_{4n} 40\sqrt{3} = \log_{3n} 45$, find $n^3$.

Tags: logarithms

$\log_{4n} 40\sqrt{3} = \log_{3n} 45$, find $n^3$.

I can't seem to find any identities to help me in this problem.  Any hints or answers?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set $\log_{4n} 40\sqrt{3} = \log_{3n} 45=t$, thus
\begin{cases}
4^t n^t=40\sqrt{3}\\
3^t n^t=45
\end{cases}
we have
$$\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^t=\frac{8\sqrt{3}}{9}=\frac{8}{3\sqrt 3}\implies t=\frac 32$$
finally
$$8n^{\frac 32}=40\sqrt 3$$
then
$$n^3=75$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{\log5+\dfrac{\log3}2+3\log2}{2\log2+\log n}=\dfrac{\log5+2\log3}{\log3+\log n}$$

On simplification,

$$3(2\log2-\log3)\log n=(2\log2-\log3)(2\log5-\log3)$$

$$\iff\log(n^3)=\log\dfrac{5^2}3$$  as $2\log2-\log3\ne0$

Answer (score 0):

By the given equality there exists $x$ such that $$(4n)^x=40\sqrt3\\(3n)^x=45$$
It follows $$(\frac 43)^x=\frac{8\sqrt3}{9}=(\frac{2}{\sqrt3)})^3\iff(\frac{2}{\sqrt3})^{2x}=(\frac{2}{\sqrt3)})^3\iff x=\frac32$$ 
Hence

$$(3n)^{\frac 32}=45\iff (3n)^3=(45)^2\iff n^3=\frac{(45)^2}{3^3}=75$$